# How to change GNOME app preferences for root?

Tags: gnome, root, settings

Opening the apps such as *Gedit* or *Gnome Text Editor* with `sudo` in Terminal, will open the app with default preferences and furthermore it won’t let me change those settings; however as an administrative user I have changed various preferences that seem to be ignored.

Here’s a screenshot for comparison: root vs. user

[image: user preferences ignored using root]

When trying to change the preferences after opening the app with sudo, I get the following error/warning in Terminal (in which `tedit` is a symbolic link to `gnome-text-editor`):

```
(tedit:37067): dconf-WARNING **: 11:36:56.149: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=cca92021290f49f5b00d396a
```

So, **is there a way to change preferences for root to be followed when opening the app with root privileges?**

I tried the following with no success:

1. Logging in as root with `su root` and then opening the app;
2. Opning the app using `gksu`;
3. Editing the default parameters of gsettings schema for the specific app in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.TextEditor.gschema.xml`;
4. Opening the directory `/usr/share/applications` as administrator and then launch the app using .desktop files.

---

### Edit 1

I just found out the option `sudo -E` as a workaround to open a file with root but in my user environment, for examle:

```
sudo -E gnome-text-editor [path-to-file]
```

But I’m still eager to know if there’s a straightforward method to change root preferences permanently.

---

### Edit 2

I found out accidentally that the foremenitoned method (3), i.e. changing schema’s default values, does work but you need to recompile them with:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Yet I consider this as another workaround, not a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the settings... In this case (`gedit` preferences) the settings are normally stored in a binary file via `dconf` (in the respective user's `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`). However, since `dconf` doesn't have access to a `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRES` when you invoke `gedit` with `sudo` (that's why you get those warning messages), it doesn't work. People usually try to work around by getting the address, exporting it etc
I think the most straightforward way is via [`dbus-run-session`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-run-session.1.html) e.g. to set the `gedit` color scheme to *solarized dark* for the root you could run:

```
sudo -i -u root sh -c 'exec dbus-run-session -- gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme "solarized-dark"'
```

or, open directly `gedit`

```
sudo -i -u root sh -c 'exec dbus-run-session -- gedit'
```

and customize as you wish, the settings will be saved for the next time you run `sudo gedit`.